What is the optimal way to resolve the asset cache issue after flutter deprecated loadEntrypoint function
A part of my index.html code used to be like below. I use to run a script to create buildVersion directory, move assets there and template the {{buildVersion}} after the flutter build web job completes which would solve the cache issue related to assets (js files, images) on each layer of my infra (cloudflare, browser etc..)
        entrypointUrl: "/a/{{buildVersion}}/main.dart.js",
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          serviceWorkerUrl: "{{buildVersion}}/flutter_service_worker.js?v=" + serviceWorkerVersion
        },

Flutter seems to have deprecated this function and insists using the _flutter.loader.load() api with which I am unable to configure my entrypoint (main.dart.js). Is there a better way to resolve the cache issue with the new paradigm? I was not able to find any documentation around it..
Thanks in advance!!

You are right, there is no entrypointUrl anymore.
The updated information about Flutter web app initialization can be found here: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/bootstrapping
Therefore, the versioning solution would look like this:
<body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
    {{flutter_js}}
    {{flutter_build_config}}

    _flutter.loader.load({
      serviceWorker: {
        serviceWorkerVersion: {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
        serviceWorkerUrl: "flutter_service_worker.js?v=" + {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
      },
      onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
        engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
          appRunner.runApp();
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

as a replacement of default:
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>


Thanks @AnyWhereRom but this would just invalidate the flutter_service-worker.js from the cache. The main.dart.js would still be stale. Is it not the case?

In order for this to work you should append service worker version to main.dart.js, here is an example code from one of my projects:
const serviceWorkerVersion = {{flutter_service_worker_version}};

window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
  {{flutter_js}}
  {{flutter_build_config}}

  _flutter.buildConfig.builds[0].mainJsPath = "main.dart.js?v=" + serviceWorkerVersion;

  _flutter.loader.load({
    serviceWorkerSettings: {
      serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
    },
    onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
      engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
          appRunner.runApp();
      });
    }
  });
});

